# How to properly implement a data sync between mobile client database and server mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, spring-boot, data-synchronization

I've developed an android app that allows users to log certain activities. I now want to add a feature where users can back-up the data to a server so that if they have multiple devices, they can just download from it.

I started working on a Spring-Boot based web application. This will be purely json and will not have a web-ui.

I came upon a question regarding primary keys and foreign keys. For example I have this table on the server.

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT
, activity_date DATETIME
, notes TEXT
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This table on the SQLite on the client.

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT
, activity_date LONG
, notes TEXT
);
```

When the user creates the activity record offline, it will generate a primary key. When the user goes online, I will have to sync the data by doing an httpPost. However, I can't use the id generated as it might cause duplicate issues.

What kind of approach can I use on this?

Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok. So based on comments from Jorge Moreno and nuuneoi, I've come up with this design.

**UPDATE 2**

After looking at the design, I might have missed a column in the client side. Added device_id column there as well.

I figured that local_id could be similar across user devices so adding device_id would make it impossible to have similar values using both device_id and local_id.

Server

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, device_id VARCHAR(100) -- Actual Devices Id (e.g. Phone, Tablet). To handle if a user has multiple devices
, local_id INT
, user_id INT
, activity_date DATETIME
, notes TEXT
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Client

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT
, device_id TEXT -- Added on UPDATE 2
, activity_date LONG
, notes TEXT
);
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Don´t  sent the id value from sqlite, sql server had the id autoincrement

Answer (score 1):

How's about this table on the server.

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, local_id INT
, user_id INT
, activity_date DATETIME
, notes TEXT
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and this table on SQLite?

```
CREATE TABLE user_activities (
  local_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT
, activity_date LONG
, notes TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few threads listed below, I've decided to use UUID as my primary key columns and just generate some random UUID from each client.

[how good is java's UUID.randomUUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid)
[Android (distributed application) primary key strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263250/android-distributed-application-primary-key-strategy)